# Sending cache headers only for a single request [or for a request following a certain path string]

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, cache, http-headers, proxypass

I have the proxy pass in nginx config defined as follows:

```
location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
        add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
        if_modified_since off;
        expires off;
        etag off;
        proxy_read_timeout 300s;
        proxy_connect_timeout 300s;
        proxy_send_timeout 300s;
        send_timeout 300s;
}
```

As you could see, `Cache-Control` header is being passed, which tells to cache nothing. But for one of the request which has path `/load-custom-js`, I want to return a different cache header which tells browser to cache the response. How could I do this? Would I need to add a new proxy pass block?

Answer (score 0):

One can use nginx `map` for this. On the `http` level, define map like this:

```
map $request_uri $cachecontrol {
    default 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
    "~^/load-custom-js " 'CACHE_HEADER';
}
```

And in your `location` block, use the `$cachecontrol` variable as follows:

```
add_header Cache-Control $cachecontrol;
```

You might want to add several `map` variables for `expires`, `etag` and `if_modified_since`. They would work in the same fashion.